# Tiktok events - "View Content" vs "Page View"

Tags: analytics, tiktok

TL;DR -
what event should I send to TikTok when a user visits my site - "Page View" or "View Content"?

I implemented event-tracking with TikTok on my site, both with tiktok-pixel (browser) and tiktok Events API (with GTM server-side).

To send the event in GTM server container, I'm using stape.io's [TikTok Events API tag](https://stape.io/blog/how-to-set-up-tiktok-events-api).
I noticed that the standard events they offer do no include "Page View" - they include "View Content", so that's what I'm sending.
The TikTok documentation explains that "Page View" is deprecated, and that "View Content"  replaces it and a bunch of other events, however it is still sent ([here](https://ads.tiktok.com/help/article?aid=10028) and [here](https://ads.tiktok.com/help/article?aid=10002463)).

What confuses me the most is that "View Content" - the event replacing "Page View" - is not automatically sent! And no guid recommends sending it on every page-view.

As I mentioned, the standard tiktok-pixel base-tracking code still sends "Page View" events:

```
ttq.page();
```

I modified it to send a specific event_id, which I also send from my sGTM, so that tiktok can [deduplicate](https://ads.tiktok.com/marketing_api/docs?id=1723170195197953) the events:

```
ttq.page({event_id: "PageView_{{page_view Event ID}}"});
```

But since I'm sending "Page View" from the browser, and "View Content" from the sGTM -
The result is 2 different events:
[image: tiktok events - pageviews and viewcontents]

So The question is -
What event should I send, from both ends?

- PageView?
- ViewContent?
- Both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have your same setup, client side and server tracking with stape.io. I use the "Page View" event on all pages of the site while the "View Content" event only on Category and Product pages. Therefore, the "Page View" event will be triggered in all the pages of the site, while both the "Page View" and "View Content" events will be triggered on Category and Product pages as also specified in the [TikTok documentation](https://ads.tiktok.com/help/article?aid=10002463):

> View Content
>
> Tracks the product categories page URL
>
> Tracks the product details page URL

The "View Content" event is a step after the "Page View" event, it indicates that the user is interested in a certain category or product and therefore is slightly lower in the funnel.

Comment: Thanks.
It sounds right.

I wish TikTok would've recommended sending "PageView" from Events API themselves...